# Using a map() function as a condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, map-function

I have two DataFrames, one gets daily new inputs via Id number and gives the related value. The other one corresponds to a "catalog" that lists all existing Ids and outputs the name of the corresponding Id.

So the Output looks like this:

```
daily input
    date        id  value
0   2010-03-01  2   57.9
1   2010-10-14  1   79.1
2   2010-12-18  3   0.0


catalog
    name         id
0   aba           1
1   aba-1         2
2   aba-2         3
3   aba           4
4   aba-2         5
```

Now I want to build a function, whose first condition is, which name has the following ID and from this follows further subconditions, in order to return the appropriate value.

```
def numfunc (id, date):  
     if (id == (map(catalog.set_index("id")["name"])) == "aba-1"):
        if date.dayofweek == 5: 
                return 50
     else:
           return 25

df['num']= daily_input.apply(lambda x:numfunc(x['id'],x['date']),axis=1)
```

So I'm only concerned with the first line here **if (id == (map(catalog.set_index("id")["name"])) == "B")**, whether this can be used that way at all?. When executing this function I get the error message: **map() must have at least two arguments**.

Goal Output:

```
df 
    date        id  num
0   2010-03-01  2   25
1   2010-10-14  1   25
2   2010-12-18  3   25
```

Many thanks for your support.

Comment: `map` is irrelevant there. You can succeed with just filtering. `df` is the 3rd dataframe in your case, how does it look like?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks for the answer! Just updated the question and added the DataFrame df, which is my target DataFrame.
Does filtering also work if there are multiple Ids that could have the same name? In my case, i would get some ids daily and each of them should go through the catalog to tell me if it belongs to aba, aba-1 or aba-2 and based on that they follow the next condition.

Comment: Why does your final df contains `id=3  num=50` as id=3 does **not** meet the condition `name == "aba-1"` ?

Comment: Because I inserted the table manually (dummy values). You are right, in this case there should be 25 now and not 50. Is corrected. But from the principle, I can't get to the line that should first check if the id is either "aba", "aba-1" or "aba-2".